# Property 'FC' does not exist on type 'typeof React

Tags: react-tsx

Version
"typescript": "^3.9.5"
"@types/react": "^16.9.36",
Property 'FC' does not exist on type 'typeof React
I'm all out of ideas.

In .tsx files that contain react, I am continually getting the errors:

Property 'FC' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.

and

I get this in every .tsx file that contains react.

I know it has to be some combination of my Visual Studio configuration and the project config.

Anyone have any ideas for what to check that would only affect some workstations? I can provide as much as I can without giving away company info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encountered this problem due to syntax error on my end.
If you are migrating from React native to the typescript one, check whether you converted the following properly:

```
function Counter(props: {initialCount: string}) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
interface CounterProps {
    initialCount: string
}

const Counter : React.FC<CounterProps> = (props: CounterProps) => {
    ...
}
```

If this does not solve the problem then check whether the React that is getting imported, from where is it getting imported?

FC can be found in @types/react in `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts/React`.

Comment: Sir Thanks I really appreciate the time you take in answering questions. May you always be happy.

Answer (score 3):

In case it's useful for anyone, this error message came up for me when I misspelled my component definition with an `=` sign instead of `:`.

So, I had written:

```
const My Component = React.FC<Iprops> = (props) => {}
```

instead of:

```
const My Component : React.FC<Iprops> = (props) => {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart IDE worked for me, all new files got this error until restarted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally wrote

```
class Square: React.FC<ISquare> = ({}) => {
    return (<></>)
}
```

instead of

```
const Square: React.FC<ISquare> = ({}) => {
    return (<></>)
}
```